# Close overlay by clicking on background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to close an overlay window by clicking on the outer body only.
The problem is that the overlay get closed even if I click on the overlay panel itself and if I click on any other element i put in it (divs, buttons, icons etc etc...)
I don't know how to target only the body around the overlay and not the overlay window itself.
Can you please help?

Here is both html markup and related JS.

```
<div id="main">
    <div class"other-content">
        <!-- other content -->
    </div>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal__content">
            <!-- some content - divs, buttons etc etc -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
       $(document).on('click',"#myModal", function(e) {       
          $('#myModal').fadeOut();                
       });
```

Comment: How you can click on out of body?

Comment: good that you found a working solution, but please don't include it in your question! keep your problem in the question, and create an answer below.

Comment: @Jeremy, you right. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a click event on `<body>`, with **[`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)** to check for elements.

```
$('body').on('click',function(e) {
     var $currEl = $(e.currentTarget);
     if(!$currEl.is('#myModal') && !$currEl.closest('#myModal').length){
        $('#myModal').fadeOut();    
     }
     else if(/write code element which triggers modal open even/){
        $('#myModal').fadeIn(); //or any code to trigger modal open 
     }
});
```

1. `$currEl.is('#myModal')` checks if the current clicked elements is `myModal`
2. `$currEl.closest('#myModal').length` checks if the current element in inside/child of `myModal`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as the solution offered below by Jeremy. It opens the overlay and closes it immediately afterwards. Don't understand why. Any alternative?

Comment: You need to write an `else..if` to write code for modal open event. Could you add the code which triggers modal open in your question. I'll update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 5):

This is called [event bubbling](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling). Because the modal is a child of the document, when the modal is clicked, the event propagates to any parent listeners. This is the by design. To prevent this, you can use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the modal.

For example:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
    $( '#myModal' ).fadeOut();
});

$( '#myModal' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

It's worth noting that by stopping event propagation, any events that are on parent elements of the modal will also be prevented.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2a3Lf2nx/) is an example of a super basic modal. Honestly, though, you might benefit from looking at better modal design & integration. Having a variable to keep track of whether its open or not would be good. Additionally, an overlay in the  background could serve as the only element to assign a listener to. I'm not saying this is the best way.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It opens the overlay and closes it immediately afterwards. Any alternative?

Comment: @Beppe you might have to put the selector back on. try what i have now

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work. I've done this instead but nothing -->  $(document).on('click',"#myModal", function(e) {

Comment: @Beppe thinking about it, adding the selector shouldn't make it work. if you provided all the code responsible for the modal it might be easier to hlpe

Comment: That's a delegated event handler, it targets the element with the ID `#myModal` and any child of that element. It makes little sense to target those elements, when they are the elements you don't won't fire the event for ?

Comment: @Beppe you might also try `event.preventDefault()` instead

Comment: @adeneo  The #myModal is the container of the overlay. I need to fire what is outside the modal__content class. Maybe it makes more sense now?

Comment: @Beppe he was commenting on my usage of a selector for the click listener; he's right, it doesnt makes sense to use one in this case.

Comment: @Jeremy The code responsible for the modal is the one I've provided. I have another function that only opens the modal. That's it.

Comment: @Jeremy just found a solution. See my code update above. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As my understanding you are styling:

- .modal with 100% width and height, position fixed. It also has opacity background and stay on top of everything by bigger z-index.
- .modal-content with all the content needed, different background color.

Please try the below code to detect where user are clicking in, inside or outside the modal-content.

```js
(function ($) {
    $('.modal').on('click', function (e) {
        //Check whether click on modal-content
        if (e.target !== this)
            return;

        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes both assumption and solution are correct. What solution is best according to you?

Comment: This is my pen, you can take a look. It seem we are using the same approach while implementing CSS modal. I only use the snippet as my above answer for that one. 
http://codepen.io/trungk18/pen/dXVmEE

Comment: Yes we use the same approach actually. Useful example! Thanks for your help.

Comment: This isn't exact my problem, but your answer help to me!

Answer (score 2):

Found a working solution. See below.

```
   $(document).on('click',"#myModal", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              if(e.target.id === "myModal"){
                $('#myModal').fadeOut();
              }
   });
```

Comment: Consider simply hiding your modal rather than fading it out, to keep your users happy.  Users don't care about transitions unless it helps them understand how things work.  Fading out your modal just adds another third of a second they have to wait to do what they want to do.  Also, you should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an `.on('click'...)` to the whole document, I would just add another layer div that acts as a background and a trigger.

Everbody here is thinking too complicated I think, (despite the fact, that the stuff about event bubbling etc. is correct).

Since you have asked for an alternative, this is how I do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    color: #888;
}

#main {
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    padding: 20px;
}

.other-content {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
    padding: 20px;
}

#myModal {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #545454;
}


.modal-inner-content {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
    color: #666;
    padding: 20px;
    background: white;
}

</style>
<script>
// All pure, beautiful Vanilla JS
// This is only dumb toggle.. 1 and 0
function toggleModalWindow() {
// For scrollbar Handling
var body = document.getElementById('top')
// first, grab the id of the outer modal window
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Then get the "status" (open or closed) of that previously declared   variable
var status = modal.getAttribute('data-status');
    // Now we do simple if check if it is open or closed
    if(status === 'closed') {
    // Make the modal block, then manipulate it's opacity slowly
    modal.style.display = "block";
    // We hide the browser sidebar
    body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    // don't forget to set the attributes again
        modal.setAttribute('data-status', 'open');
    } else {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    // show browser sidebar again
    body.style.overflowY = "visible";
    // don't forget to set the attributes again
    modal.setAttribute('data-status', 'closed');
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body id="top">
<div id="main">
<div class"other-content">
    <h1>Awesome Content</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae saepe odio, labore ad, cum repudiandae non officia asperiores. Sequi porro magni corporis.</p>
</div>
<div class="other-content">
    <button onclick="toggleModalWindow();">show me that badASs modal</button>
</div>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal" data-status="closed" onclick="toggleModalWindow();">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal__content">
        <div class="modal-inner-content">
            <h2>Modal Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum enim sapiente eius, asperiores ea mollitia velit accusamus soluta similique nobis modi obcaecati veritatis labore temporibus nulla, hic aliquid nam error!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```